# How can i Pull or display one secondary manager name instead two secondary managers

Tags: sql, oracle

I have multiple secondary managers for each agreement. I just need one. But the primary key is unique how can I do that?

This is how my data looks:
[image: This is how my data looks]

Comment: Please elaborate " I just need one.."

Comment: Please do not post links to images.  Edit the question, and put in as text.  Thanks. What have you tried?  Please show expected output.

Comment: @Dharmesh That is cryptic, isn't it? Maybe I'm answering the wrong question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the [first normal form (1NF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). You are looking at your primary and secondary owners, and thinking that you could do something of the same with your managers, and getting stuck when you realize that there is a variable number of secondary managers.

You have a "many-to-many" relationship between agreements and managers: an agreement has multiple managers and a manager has multiple agreements. The way to resolve this is to create three tables: one for agreements, one for managers and one for a single manager and a single agreement. Like this:

```
Agreements
ID
Other stuff

Managers
ID
Other stuff

AgreementsManagers
AgreementID
ManagerID
```

All fields with "ID" in them are primary key fields. So the "associative entity" (AgreementsManagers in this example) has two key fields, and therefore has a "composite primary key."

You also need to do something similar with owners. Put the owners in a separate table. If there are always two and only two owners per agreement, you can get away with and putting their IDs in the primary and secondary owner fields in your agreements table. If there is a variable number of owners per agreement, you should remove the owner fields from the agreements table entirely and set up an associative entity such as I've given you in the example.

Comment: I wont be able to create new tables. I am just asking is there a way i can get top most manager for the same agreement

Comment: @user10260750 In that case, you'll need to post your table structure and ask that question specifically, along with whatever DBMS you are using -- they all do the topmost thing differently. So far, the best answer anyone can give you is "yes, there probably is."

Comment: SELECT *
FROM VR_FEI.VS_SECONDARY_MANAGER SM
WHERE SM.SOURCING_MANAGER IN (SELECT SM.SOURCING_MANAGER FROM VR_FEI.VS_SECONDARY_MANAGER SM 
                              GROUP BY SM.SOURCING_MANAGER
                              HAVING COUNT (*)>1);

Comment: can we use this?